# Does the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty } \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} } $ converges uniformly on $\left [ 0,\infty \right )$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Does the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty } \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} } $ converges uniformly on $\left [ 0,\infty  \right )$? Prove or disprove it.

My first attempt is try to use Weierstrass M-test:$$\left |\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} }  \right | =\frac{1}{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} } =\frac{1}{ne^{\frac{x}{n}} }< \frac{1}{ne^{\frac{0}{n}} }=\frac{1}{n}......(1)    $$
but unfortunately $\sum_{1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n} $ is divergent, so (1) tell me nothing.

My second attempt is try to use Dirichlet test:$$\left | \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left ( -1 \right ) ^n \right | < 2 \qquad \forall  x\in \left [0,\infty   \right ) ...\space this \space condition \space is \space OK$$

Next assume $b(n)=\frac{e^{\frac{-x}{n}}}{n} $, then...$$b'{(n)} =\frac{ \left (e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\times \frac{x}{n^2}\times n  \right ) - \left ( e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\times1 \right ) }{n^2}= \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\times \left ( \frac{x}{n}-1  \right )  }{n^2}$$
sadly, it seems not to decrease monotonically to zero, so this condition has failed.

What should I do in order to test the uniform convergence of this series on  $\left [ 0,\infty  \right )$?

Comment: @Lelouch The problem in your deleted answer was not for $x=0$
 but for $x→+∞.$
 Btw, this absence of decreasing monotonicity at $x=+∞$
 was already noticed by the OP.

Comment: Madam would you please give me the link of the question you mentioned about earlier? I somehow accidentally missed it.

Comment: Sure, but it does not help here because your $e^{-x/n}$ is not $e^{-nx}.$ The link was [The convergence of power series of $\log(1+x)$ with or without Taylor expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466817). I found it [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_1%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(-x%5Cright)%5En%7D%7Bn%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Auniform&p=1).

Comment: Too bad, so sad, but still thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}ne^{-\frac xn}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,+\infty),$ as the sum of:

- a convergent series independent of $x:$
  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n=-\ln2$$
- an alternating series which will be proved uniformly convergent:
  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}a_n,\quad\text{with}\quad a_n:=\frac{1-e^{-x/n}}n\ge0.$$

The positive sequence $(a_n)$ converges *uniformly* to $0$ (since $a_n<\frac1n$) and is moreover decreasing (contrarily to the original sequence $\left(\frac{e^{-\frac xn}}n\right)$), as the [product of two positive decreasing sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808849): $\left(\frac1n\right)$ and $\left(1-e^{-\frac xn}\right).$

Therefore, [the usual criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) applies (uniformly as can be seen from [its proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Proof_of_the_alternating_series_test), since the convergence of $(a_n)$ to $0$ is uniform) and the conclusion follows.

Comment: thank you madam! I'll study this later.

Comment: Madam, would you please help me with my latest question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4704358/1180314

Comment: Excuse me madam, could you please take a look of this question of mine?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715103/prove-sum-n-1-infty-binomkn-converges-absolutely

Answer (score 4):

The series in question can be written as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} }
=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n} }}{2n}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n-1} }}{2n-1}\right].
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=M}^{\infty } \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} }
=\begin{cases}
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n} }}{2n}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n+1}\right]&,\quad M/2\in \Bbb N\\
\sum_{n=(M+1)/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n-1} }}{2n-1}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n} }}{2n}\right]&,\quad (M+1)/2\in \Bbb N
\end{cases}.
$$
We prove uniform convergence for the case of $M/2\in\Bbb N$. The other case is deduced likewise.

For $M/2\in\Bbb N$, using $e^{-\frac{x}{2n}}<e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1}}$ we obtain
$$
{
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n} }}{2n}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n+1}\right]
{
< 
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n+1}\right]
\\=
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n(2n+1)}
\\\le
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}
\\\le
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}
\\=\frac{1}{2M-2}
}
}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n} }}{2n}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n+1}\right]
{
=
\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{M} }}{M}-
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+1} }}{2n+1}-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+2} }}{2n+2}\right]
\\\ge
\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{M} }}{M}-
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2n+2} }}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
\\\ge
\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{M} }}{M}-
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
\\\ge
\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{M} }}{M}-
\sum_{n=M/2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2n(2n+2)}
\\=
\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{M} }}{M}-
 \frac{1}{2M}
\ge -\frac{1}{2M}.
}
$$
Therefore $\left|\sum_{n=M}^{\infty } \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} }{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n} }\right|\le\frac{1}{M}$ for $M/2\in\Bbb N$. A similar approach can be taken for $(M+1)/2\in\Bbb N$, which proves that *the series is uniformly convergent*.

Comment: Wow! thank you sir!  I can't believe that this question was put in a entrance examination. This is so difficult!

Comment: Wow indeed! I first couldn't believe it, but then it gave me the idea of [a simpler proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704206/386889).